# Cypress issue with connection to the site is not secure?

Tags: security, https, connection, cypress

I'm testing the website which have request to optimizely api to do some checking.

It request to url like https://cdn.optimizely.com/datafiles/XXX.json I suppose that this site required secure network.

I tried to open the url in cypress chrome and I get this error
This page isn’t workingcdn.optimizely.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

But when I tried with the same network in chrome, I get fine response.

[image]

I need to be able to load the url to test my site.

Is there any solution to this matter. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cypress will not load optimizely neither nor google-analytics or any . My work around solution is by using cy.intercept() function in before/beforeEach

The code looks something like

```
cy.intercept('https://cdn.optimizely.com/datafiles/XXX8.json', {
        "version": "4"
}
```

Reference: [cypress-example-recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__google-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

The resource returns [403 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403), that most likely indicates you don't have sufficient rights to see it:

[image]

Your Chrome outside Cypress runs might be set up differently, might already have session cookies.

You most likely need to figure out how to log into some account on the site throught Cypress.

Comment: Thank you @pavelsaman. Do you have cypress installed ? Can you try if you get the same error in cypress ?